# segmentation fault after main returns

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, program-entry-point

I have a long program in c over Linux, that gives me segmentation fault after main returns.
Its a long program, so I cant post it. So can you help me what can make such error?

Thank You.

Wow, Those answers came really fast. Thank you all.
I think i worked it out, i forgot to malloc a string and used it as buffer.
Now that I've malloced it, it does not signal me with a segmentation fault.

Once again, thank you all.

Comment: Try this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718998/methodology-for-fixing-segmentation-faults-in-c

Comment: Without having a single line of code to look at we may as well tell you a random answer. In general, however, is pointer-related stuff (including buffer overflows) or stack corruption.

Comment: Did you declare your main function as returning void?

Comment: You probably trashed some memory somewhere in your code - try running under valgrind.

Comment: Post your code at http://pastebin.com/ so that everyone can see it

Comment: How do you know it's after `main()` returns?

Comment: I've edited my post, please check it.
And Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Guess: you might be accidentally corrupting the stack in main so it's lost the return address. Do you have a string buffer there that you could be overrunning?

If not, you should try:

- running the program under valgrind
- debugging the program with gdb to catch the crash and see where you are at that point; you can also debug the core file dumped

It might help to install glibc-debug packages if your distro has them since you'll be in glibc code at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Use GDB and print stack trace on SIGSEGV signal. Then at least post **that** here so we can be a little bit more helpful.

Provided you compiled with:

```
$ gcc -g prog.c -o prog
```

Then run it under GDB:

```
$ gdb ./prog
gdb> r
```

When you get `SIGSEGV` signal (Segmentation Fault), do this:

```
gdb> bt
```

Then see what's on the stack trace to see what is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Very useful suggestion. People who are trying to develop based on another huge system always cannot find the exact point that cause the segfault without debugging like this.

Answer (score 1):

If the segmentation fault arises after main() returns, it usually means that a global defined thing went wrong. It is hard to help you with so little info. Send us more info !

my2c

Answer (score 1):

If it's after `main()` returns, then according to the Standard all destructors have been run (although I wouldn't put it past an implementation to fudge this some), unless the function `atexit()` has been used.  That function registers a function that will be called after `main()` returns, effectively (if I'm reading 3.6.3 aright).  You might check to see if there is an `atexit` in your program somewhere, if only for completeness.

Depending on what you mean by "after main returns", you may be running destructors for static objects when the program crashes.  Check those.  (Also, post what you observed that made you think it was after `main()` returned.  You could be wrong there.)

If not, then you've invoked undefined behavior somewhere, very likely in corrupting the stack somehow.  See Rup's answer for suggestions there.