# Adapter pattern in C++ returning a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn C++ and design patterns, I am doing this by translating the Java code from [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm) to C++ and run it so I can learn advanced C++ syntax (at least I think so, correct me if I am wrong).
I translated to code in that page, and compiled it using Digital Mars. It compiled, but when I try to run it, I get nothing. I went online and tried several online C++ compilers, it compiles but running it returns a **segmentation fault** errors which is to the best to my knowledge is trying to access a memory location that I am not allowed to.

I am new to C++, what did I do wrong to cause such an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MediaPlayer {
public:
 virtual void play(string audioType, string fileName);
};

class AdvancedMediaPlayer { 
public:
 virtual void playVlc(string fileName);
 virtual void playMp4(string fileName);
};

class VlcPlayer : public AdvancedMediaPlayer{
    
public:
void playVlc(string fileName) {
      cout << "Playing vlc file. Name: "<< fileName;        
   }

    
void playMp4(string fileName);
};

class Mp4Player : public AdvancedMediaPlayer{
    
public:
void playVlc(string fileName);
    
void playMp4(string fileName) {
      cout << "Playing mp4 file. Name: "<< fileName;        
   }
};

class MediaAdapter : public MediaPlayer {

AdvancedMediaPlayer* advancedMusicPlayer;

public:
MediaAdapter(string audioType){
  
      if(audioType.compare("vlc")==0 ){
         advancedMusicPlayer = new VlcPlayer;
         
      }else if (audioType.compare("mp4")==0){
         advancedMusicPlayer = new Mp4Player;
      } 
   }

void play(string audioType, string fileName) {
   
      if(audioType.compare("vlc")==0){
         advancedMusicPlayer->playVlc(fileName);
      }
      else if(audioType.compare("mp4")==0){
         advancedMusicPlayer->playMp4(fileName);
      }
   }
};

class AudioPlayer : public MediaPlayer {

MediaAdapter* mediaAdapter; 
    
public:
  void play(string audioType, string fileName) {        

         if( (audioType.compare("mp3"))==0){
         cout << "Playing mp3 file. Name: " << fileName;            
      } 
       
      else if( (audioType.compare("vlc"))==0 || (audioType.compare("mp4"))==0){
         mediaAdapter = new MediaAdapter(audioType);
         mediaAdapter->play(audioType, fileName);
      }
      
      else{
         cout << "Invalid media. " << audioType << " format not supported";
      }
   }   
};

int main() {
      AudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
      audioPlayer->play("mp3", "beyond the horizon.mp3");
      audioPlayer->play("mp4", "alone.mp4");
      audioPlayer->play("vlc", "far far away.vlc");
      audioPlayer->play("avi", "mind me.avi");
   }
```

Comment: Sorry pasted it wrong.

Comment: I don't think that "tutorialsoint" does such futile mistake. I've checked the link. It is not on C++ but Java maybe. be honest.

Comment: Don't edit the topic that way.

Comment: I said that I am translating Java to C++.

Comment: `AudioPlayer *audioPlayer;` is not a valid pointer yet.

Comment: Okay, a few comments. First, it will help a lot if you can identify where you're getting the segmentation violation. Either produce a core file and dump it, use a debugger, or add debug output to figure out where. Second, this is very strange polymorphism. Is there some reason your base class doesn't have a virtual void play() method, and your child classes each override that to play properly? Your USE of the object shouldn't have to if-check and call different player types. That's what polymorphism is supposed to do for you.

Comment: I am following their code and trying to understand it.

Comment: I advice you keep away from doing that because each language has its own convention among which memory management. for example C++ allow memory management through raw pointer will Java doesn't this will cause serious problems when dealing and "translating" from a language to the other.

Comment: @user10191234 See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718998/fixing-segmentation-faults-in-c) please.

Comment: @user10191234 *I said that I am translating Java to C++* -- You are trying to write C++ code using Java as a model, at least that is the impression from the code you've written.  Do not do this, as trying to write C++ programs using Java as a model will either result in buggy programs, inefficient programs, or a combination of those two items.  Maybe even worse, the programs will look nothing like an idiomatic C++ program, basically looking plain weird to a C++ programmer.  This: `AudioPlayer *audioPlayer;` is an indication of this issue.  All you need should do is `AudioPlayer audioPlayer;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, `AudioPlayer audioPlayer` didn't work either.

Comment: The point is that there are a lot of things you're doing that is making your code not work, and most of it is due to trying to write C++ code as if it's Java.  There is no need for pointers for most of your program, including `mediaAdapter = new MediaAdapter(audioType);`.

Comment: I get that it is not a helpful question, but I am not allowed to delete it.

Comment: After changing the `AudioPlayer audioPlayer;` and then using `audioPlayer.` instead of `audioPlayer->`, there are no compiler errors.  The only errors are linker errors, as [seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c885d2651ee1c0e2).  You need to actually provide the `play` functions you are calling for the program to actually pass the link phase.

Comment: `play` is implemented in `AudioPlayer` and `MediaAdapter`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I find most Java developers like to embellish their code a lot.  It's usually overcomplicated.  Over use of useless classes and other anti-patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Good on you for learning C++.

"**Segmentation fauled ... what did I do wrong to cause such an error."** ?

Unfortunately, you've made a classic mistake in your program.

Right here.  audioPlayer is a pointer.  What do you think it points to?

```
AudioPlayer *audioPlayer // <---- The problem is here.  It's not initialised before you go to use it on the next line!
audioPlayer->play("mp3", "beyond the horizon.mp3"); // <--- It crashes here!
```

You have not initalised the pointer for the audioPlayer object.
It could point anywhere in memory.  You haven't allocated an object to it.
Something like this will get you further.

```
AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
// ...  do stuff
delete audioPlayer;  // Free it at the end.
```

Or if AudioPlayer is to exist for the lifetime of the app perhaps just

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
audioPlayer.Play("mp3", "beyond the horizon.mp3");
// etc.  No need for new / delete.
```

Comment: You should also show the OP how to free that memory once no mre needed otherwise the memory leaks. `delete audioPlayer`. such answers should be in comments I guess.

Comment: I could... but I'm not here to re-write his code, just point him in the right direction.

Comment: Half right direction I think. It is not about rewriting the code but as you know validating an invalid pointer ten leaking memory is another serious problem.

Comment: `delete AudioPlayer();` ? are you serious?

Comment: Settle down.  It's a copy paste typo.

Comment: With the current code status your suggestion won't work.

Comment: @Joe Op is asking the question "what did I do wrong to cause such an error." (seg fault) The answer is uninitialized pointer.  Nothing much more needs to be said.  I'm not critiquing his code.