# Segmentation fault in C++ adding item to a vector

Tags: c++, macos, segmentation-fault

Lately I have set myself to learn C++, and while working on a bigger project, I have tried to use 'vectors'. But every-time I try passing it a value, it exits with a segmentation fault.

Here is my terminal output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> test;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    test[0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

```
me@my-MacBook-Pro Desktop % g++ test.cpp -o o && ./o
hello world
zsh: segmentation fault  ./o
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> test;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
   //test[0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

```
me@my-MacBook-Pro Desktop % g++ test.cpp -o o && ./o
hello world
me@my-MacBook-Pro Desktop %
```

Comment: You have to resize the vector first (or pass the size to the ctor).

Comment: Perhaps you want to talk push_back() to add a value to the vector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing Segmentation faults in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718998/fixing-segmentation-faults-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size it `vector<int> test = {0,1,2,3,4};` or `vector<int> test(5)`

But you might want to use push_back in this situation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
    vector<int> test;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    test.push_back(0);
    cout << test[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Basically adds an item at the end.

Can also use maps with the keys be ints if you want to be able to just [] it or leave in spaces (which from what i saw is what your trying to do)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unordered_map<int, int> test;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    test[0] = 0;
    cout << test[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The segfault is because of out of bound access.
you need to set the size in the ctor

```
vector<int> test(1);
```

or push_back:

```
vector<int> test;
test.push_back(0);
```

Comment: A 3rd option is to use `resize(1)` on an already constructed `vector`.

Comment: But if I want to leave a slot empty ?

Comment: @Loeffelan Then you should use `std::map`

Comment: @Loeffelan I think there is XY problem here. You should first explain what you are trying to do.