# Finding memory overruns

Tags: c++, android, java-native-interface

I have a legacy C++ code which is ported to Android. When calling free on strings, a random crash is occurring. Crash is observed in random places. Is there a tool which can be used to check the memory overruns?

Comment: Are you really calling `free` on C++ data structures? Or are you just a C programmer using `free` instead of `delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try my [non-intrusive heap debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835416/critique-my-non-intrusive-heap-debugger).

Answer (score 4):

If it's due to an underlying bug that only happens to cause issues on Android, can you just run it on the legacy platform using Valgrind?

Comment: Can Valgrind be run as static analyzer as it cannot be used inside Android?

Comment: I don't know if Valgrind has been ported to Android.  What I'm suggesting is that presumably this "legacy" application used to run on some other platform.  Does Valgrind support that old platform?