# The differences between free in C and delete in C++?

Tags: c, free, delete-operator

I know the free operation in **C** is to tell the compiler this particular memory block is free for compiler to use for further allocation, but the memory is not released.

What about the delete in C++? the same as free?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. But you can overload new/delete implementations and do your own thing http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261963/176769

Comment: @karlphilip delete will call the destructor, free won't do that, and that's a pretty huge difference

Comment: You don't tell the compiler, you tell the runtime. And the memory may or may not be actually returned to the operating system depending on implementation-specific conditions. Usually small-blocks are obtained from ever-growing heap (so reused but not returned) while large-blocks are obtained from system as separate entities (using mmap or similar) and returned to system when freed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two notions of `delete` in C++: One is the *operator*, declared as `::operator delete(void*)`, which basically only frees up the memory and isn't usually thought about by most programmers. The other is the *delete expression*, `delete p;`, where `p` is a `T*`. The expression invokes the destructor of the object pointed to by `p` (and then frees the memory), which is a crucial language feature of C++ that has no analogue in C.

As a rule of thumb, you pair `new` expressions with `delete` expressions, and `malloc()` function calls with `free()` function calls:

```
T * p = new T;        // constructor called!
delete p;             // destructor called!

void * x = malloc(5); // just raw memory
free(x);              // freed
```

---

**Advanced part (not in response to the OP's question)**

Dynamic object lifetime in C++ follows this general pattern: Allocate, construct, destroy, deallocate. The standard `new` expression performs allocation and construction, while the standard `delete` expression performs destruction and deallocation.

You could write out the process manually:

```
T * p = (T*)::operator new(sizeof(T));   // allocate raw memory
p = new (p) T;                           // call the constructor ("placement new")

/*...*/

p->~T();                                 // destroy the object
::operator delete(p);                    // deallocate the memory
```

In fact, if you really wanted to implement Baby's First C++, you could define the *operators* as just as `malloc`/`free`:

```
void * operator new(size_t n) { return malloc(n); }
void   operator delete(void * p) { free(p); }
```

The real C++ magic happens by virtue of the `new` and `delete` *expressions*: The standard `new` expression invokes the constructor (a `new` expression is the *only* way to call a constructor in C++!) after allocation, while the standard delete expression invokes the destructor before deallocation.

Why "standard expression"? Well, you can also define and overload many other versions of `new` and `delete` operators. However, there is an important asymmetry: While you can use a custom `new` operator in a custom `new` expression (generally dubbed "placement new"), there is no equivalent "placement-delete" expression. So whenever you use a custom `new` expression, you have to manually invoke the destructor before calling the matching custom delete *operator*:

```
T * p = new (A, B, C) T;                          // some custom new expression

// Entirely equivalent version:

T * p = (T*) ::operator new(sizeof(T), A, B, C);  // this is your custom overload
T * p = new (p) T;                                // std. placement-new expression calls constructor

/* ---- later ---- */

p->~T();                                          // Must destroy manually!
::operator delete(p, A, B, C);                    // your matching custom overload
```

Note that there does not exist a custom delete expression `delete (A,B,C) p'`!

For completeness, the *standard placement new* operator, whose only purpose is to call a constructor, is mandated by the standard to take the following form:

```
void * operator new(size_t, void * p) { return p; }
```

It's matching `delete` *operator* is also mandated, name to do nothing:

```
void operator delete(void * p, void *) { }
```

You can see in the above general example why this is necessary.

It is important always to overload custom versions of `new` and `delete` in pairs! The reason is that if the object construction fails with an exception inside the constructor, then the memory is released by a call to the `delete` operator that matches the offending `new` expression.

---

**Second update:** To be exception-safe, we have to consider that the constructor of `T` might throw:

Version 1:

```
try {
  T * p = new (A, B, C) T;
  /* ... */
  p->~T();
  ::operator delete(p, A, B, C); // automatically invoked if T::T() throws!
}
catch(...) { }
```

Version 2:

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(T), A, B, C);
try {
  T * p = new (addr) T;  // might throw
  /* ... */
  p->~T();
  // ::operator delete(p, addr); // ditto as in (1), but does nothing
}
catch(...) { }
::operator delete(addr, A, B, C);
```

Comment: To be more precise, `delete` doesn't invoke the destructor; but compiler puts the call to destructor before wherever it finds `delete` operator. By the time you enter the function block of `delete`, the destructor is already called.

Comment: @iammilind: Your wording is a bit imprecise: If you say `::operator delete(p);`, the destructor will not get called. The destructor call is a consequence of the delete *expression*.

Comment: The "raw" calling sequence could be written out manually like this: `T * p = (T*)::operator new(sizeof(T)); p = new (p) T; p->~T(); ::operator delete(p);` You'd be insane to write that :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: Why don't you add the comments into the question text? It'd be appropriate when you're extending your own answer. As for the explicit sequence, it's important when you are defining some data structures or allocators (as in custom allocator for STL containers) for them. Things like `std::vector` have to allocate block of memory, but initialize it later. It's not something one should do regularly, but when you are after performance, you eventually need it.

Comment: @Jan: I do know that you do use explicit allocation and construction under the hood. I just thought that'd be outside the scope of the OP's interest. That's also why I didn't want to add the specifics of `operator new` replacement and allocators to this question. If you want, though, I could do it.

Comment: @Bo: But if the constructor throws an exception, I never hit those parts of the code, do I?

Comment: @Bo: well, yes, if you tear the example apart, you can run into trouble. But if you enclose the entire example in a try block, it should be fine, non?

Comment: @Kerrek - I'm being picky here, but C++0x explicitly says "Initialization of the allocated object is sequenced before the value computation of the *new-expression*", meaning that the value assigned to p isn't available until the initialization is complete. I believe this was the intent in C++03 as well.

Comment: @Bo: Please do be picky. Do you mean it should be like this: `T * p = operator new(sizeof(T)); try { p = new (p) T; /*...*/ p->~T(); } catch(...){} operator delete(p);`?

Comment: @Kerrek - No. :-) The idea is that you should start out with `void* temp = operator new(...` and not assign that to `p` until you have a complete object. (Now the chat police will soon get us).

Comment: @Bo: Oh OK, I see - I was sweeping the cast to `T*` under the carpet, which should have been a warning sign. OK, I'll edit that!

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is the same (ish) as `free`, but has important differences.  The most notable difference is that `delete` will run an objects destructor whereas `free` won't.

As the comments point out, another very important detail is not mixing malloc/free and new/delete.  If you allocate with malloc, use free and similarly if you use new, use delete!

Comment: It's a undefined behaviour to allocate with `new` and try to free with `free()` or to allocate with `malloc()` and try to free with `delete`. Some implementations will crash if you try that!

Comment: Does it work this way, `new`=>(`malloc`)=>`constructor` ; `delete`=>`destructor`=>(`free`) ? Where (`malloc`,`free`) are call "internally/automatically" . Am I rigth?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. The `delete` operator in C++ calls the object's destructor, which, depending on the implementation, should release the memory. The `delete` function can also be overloaded, where `free` cannot.

Comment: It's not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: Very true. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: @ratzip: Simply calling `delete` will call the default destructor for that object, releasing the memory.

Comment: @Evan: Formally wrong. It will call the destructor **and** release the memory. They are two separate steps and the later can be overridden per-type by defining appropriate `operator delete()` method (and corresponding `operator new()`).

Answer (score 0):

malloc() and free() are not to be used in C++ code because they don't support object semantics. Furthermore, the results of calling free() to release an object that was allocated by new, or of using delete to release memory that was allocated by malloc(), are undefined. The C++ standard doesn't guarantee that the underlying implementation of operator new uses malloc(); in fact, on some implementations malloc() and new use different heaps.
Check this [link](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=33)

delete() would delete the entire memory space occupied making it imposible to refer the varaiable once its gets deleted where in free() u could still access it.