# Using overload operator new within class

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class A and I overload operator new in the class.

```
class A{
    public:
    A();
    void *operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void *p);
}
```

How would I use this overloaded operator new inside of class A instead of the global new?
For example

```
A::A(){
    ...
    int *temp = new int[10];  //Use overloaded new and not global new
}
```

I looked around and I don't think I saw a question that addressed this.

Thanks!

Comment: [How should I write ISO C++ standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators) answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That overloaded version will be used for creating objects of `class A` and its descendants only - such as when you have `new A()` in your code. It won't be called for `new A[]` unless you overload `operator new[]()` as well.

In order to have your `operator new[]()` function used when you do `new int[]` you have to replace global `operator new()[]` function.

Comment: I know how to use the overloaded new when creating a class A. My question is, if I have a member function in class A that makes a call to new (as shown in my question above), how do I call my overloaded new instead of global new?

Comment: @Daniel W: The answer is "you can't do that". Either you replace global `operator new()[]` or you can change your code and call `operator new()` member function explicitly which will require lots of care - no constructors will be called and you will have to call `operator delete()` member function and destructors explicitly again.

Comment: `int * temp = reinterpret_cast<int*>(A::operator new (size*sizeof(int)));` - it is not suggested for real classes, I would use only by built in types.