# Overloading new operator and inheritance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I know that maybe this is not the best design in the world, but i interested in the answer
without any practical reason.

Let assume i have these two class with overloaded new methods:

```
class Base {
public:
operator void* new(size_t);
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
operator void* new(size_t); //THIS, i would like this to be the "original" new.
};

operator void* Base::new(size_t) {
//...
return new Child;
//...
}
```

I would like Child::new to work like the original new, so i could avoid using malloc.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2009/01/19/9341632.aspx) might help you...

Comment: I don't think your `Base::operator new` really 'works' (e.g. each time a `Child` is constructed it's not destroyed). Given that, it's hard to tell what you want `Child::operator new` to do. Are you sure you're not looking for factory functions?

Comment: Good Read: [How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators). I fail to understand what you ar trying to achieve So I restrain from marking this as duplicate, I do have a feeling it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always access *global* `operator new` using the syntax

```
return ::operator new( sizeof Child );
```

Note the unary scope operator. This syntax ignores any class and namespace members, and will work within either `Base::operator new` or `Child::operator new`.

To allocate and initialize the object without using class/namespace members, use

```
::new Child
```

Aside from that… yes, member `operator new` is usually a serious code smell.

Comment: I'd recommend calling `operator new`.

Comment: @LucDanton Yeah, caught that shortly after re-reading it. Mind isn't at full speed yet apparently. Also this is stinky.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Thanks! :) This is what i wanted. I will look the other links, because this is really a smelly thing. :)

Comment: Why is a member `operator new` a problem?  It's a simple way to ensure that a memory pool is used for the class, for example.  (Obviously, an `operator new`, member or otherwise, should never use the `new` operator, since its role is to return raw memory, not a constructed object.)

Comment: @JamesKanze but he's obviously not implementing his own allocator.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That's the impression I got as well, which is why my answer mostly addresses what I sort of guess he is trying to do.  But the fact that he is misusing the feature doesn't mean that it smells; class specific `operator new` is a standard idiom for memory pools.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is useful, but that idiom implies that either the allocator is hard-coded to the allocated class, because otherwise `operator new` should be a free function found by ADL on placement syntax, or that it's a singleton if placement syntax would be inapplicable. C++11 also adds TLS, allocators make relatively unsmelly singletons, and you could have a member `operator new` dispatch to a default, not singleton, pool… but taken alone, I still wouldn't call it the idiomatic primary alternative.

Comment: @Potatoswatter We're talking about member `operator new` here, so they are members of the class.  Lookup for `operator new` is a little different than for other things, ADL doesn't play a role, and the `operator new` function must be either a member or in the global namespace.

Comment: @JamesKanze "A little" ADL is used. The name is looked for in the global namespace under overload resolution, so a `friend` should be found. Anyway, even sans ADL, I stand by the same argument.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That's not what the standard says.  When you want a class specific `operator new` function, it has to be a member of the class or a base class of the class.  And you'll have to provide a corresponding `operator delete` function.

Comment: @JamesKanze Nah, I'm wrong, it's really best to use a member placement `operator new` to dispatch to the allocator. Without that the user can accidentally use another allocator. It does still work the other way, though, even including the placement delete.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Attention with placement delete.  It is only used in the special case where the constructor in a `new` expression throws.  The `operator new` function which was used in the `new` expression is not memorized.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a correct design.  An `operator new` function is supposed to
return raw memory, not a constructed object.  If your goal is for an
invocation of `new Base` to in fact create a new `Child`, it can't be
done in C++; the usual solution is to provide a factory method in
`Base`; e.g.:

```
class Base
{
    //  Ban the expression `new Base`...
    void* operator new(size_t);
protected:
    virtual ~Base();  //  Ban instances on the stack.

public:
    static Base* create(/*...*/);
    //  ...
};
```

Then in the source file:

```
class Child : public Base
{
    //  ...
};

Base* Base::create(/*...*/)
{
    return ::new Child(/*...*/);
}
```

(Note that the private `operator new` doesn't totally ban client code
from using the `new` operator, since one can always write `::new Base`.)

Other than declaring a private `operator new` to ban direct allocation,
the only use of `operator new` members is to allocate instances from a
specific pool; in which case, you also need a member `operator delete`
function to free them to the pool.

Comment: Oh, i see. It looks like i misinterpreted what that is for.