# How to use operator new to count number of times of dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
int i;
...
ostingstream os;
os<<i;
string s=os.str();
```

I want to count the number of times of dynamic memory allocation when using `ostringstream` this way. How can I do that? Maybe through `operator new`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and here is how you could do it:

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int number_of_allocs = 0;

void* operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
  ++number_of_allocs;
  void *p = malloc(size);
  if(!p) throw std::bad_alloc();
  return p;
}

void* operator new  [](std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
  ++number_of_allocs;
  void *p = malloc(size);
  if(!p) throw std::bad_alloc();
  return p;
}

void* operator new  [](std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) throw() {
  ++number_of_allocs;
  return malloc(size);
}
void* operator new   (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) throw() {
  ++number_of_allocs;
  return malloc(size);
}


void operator delete(void* ptr) throw() { free(ptr); }
void operator delete (void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw() { free(ptr); }
void operator delete[](void* ptr) throw() { free(ptr); }
void operator delete[](void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) throw() { free(ptr); }

int main () {
  int start(number_of_allocs);

  // Your test code goes here:
  int i(7);
  std::ostringstream os;
  os<<i;
  std::string s=os.str();
  // End of your test code

  int end(number_of_allocs);

  std::cout << "Number of Allocs: " << end-start << "\n";
}
```

In my environment (Ubuntu 10.4.3, g++), the answer is "2".

---

**EDIT**: Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t48aek43%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The global operator new function is called when the new operator is used to allocate objects of built-in types, objects of class type that do not contain user-defined operator new functions, and arrays of any type. When the new operator is used to allocate objects of a class type where an operator new is defined, that class's operator new is called.

So every new-expression will invoke the global `operator new`, *unless* there is a class `operator new`. For the classes you listed, I believe that there is no class-level `operator new`.

Comment: I see. So `operator new` is global in the sense that every dynamic memory allocation will require to call the redefined version if present, correct?

Comment: IMHO, delete should check for ptr being non-null.

Comment: @zzz777 I appreciate your comment, but I disagree. `free()` is defined to do nothing if passed a null pointer. Adding a check is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the dynamically allocated objects, 
You should replace the `new` operator for your class by overloading it and add the counting logic in there.

Good Read:
**[How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators)**

Comment: @littleEinstein: Check the link.

Comment: right, I know to certain extent how `operator new` works. But I am not sure how to apply it with `ostringstream`. I "desperately" need a concrete example. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux (glibc), you can use [a malloc hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Hooks-for-Malloc) to log all dynamic memory allocation.