# Why use malloc/free, when we have new/delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management

What is the use of `malloc` and `free` when we have `new` and `delete` in C++. I guess function of both `free` and `delete` is same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not the same. `new` calls the constructor, `malloc` just allocates the memory.

Also, it's **undefined behavior** mixing the two (i.e. using `new` with `free` and `malloc` with `delete`).

In C++, you're supposed to use `new` and `delete`, `malloc` and `free` are there for compatibility reasons with C.

Comment: Okk. but both of them are used for memory management. so when to use new and when to use malloc?

Comment: @Parag Doesn't "In C++, you're supposed to use new and delete" answer that? Don't use malloc/free.

Comment: @hvd: That is not the correct advice.Your rationale of just using  `new` and `delete` in C++ is not entirely correct(Especially after Nicol's reply to your comment.)

Comment: @Als Nicol's reply is a possible reason not to use `new char[]`, but no reason not to use `::operator new`, which I had mentioned in the comment he replied to. There's still no need to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, it is rarely useful that one would use `malloc` & `free` instead of `new`& `delete`.

One Scenario I can think of is:

If you do not want to get your memory initialized by implicit constructor calls, and just need an assured memory allocation for **[placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10)** then it is perfectly fine to use `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete`.

On the other hand, it is important to know that **`malloc`and `new` are not same!**
Two important differences straight up are:

- `new` guarantees callng of constructors of your class for initializing the class members while `malloc`does not, One would have to do an additional `memset` or related function calls post an `malloc` to initialize the allocated memory to do something meaningful.
- A big advantage is that for `new` you do not need to check for `NULL` after every allocation, just enclosing exception handlers will do the job saving you redundant error checking unlike `malloc`.

Comment: Sure, but an explicit call to `operator new` suffices for that, or `new char[n]`. (Nothing wrong with using malloc for that, but it's not necessary.)

Comment: @hvd: `new char[]` has some (very small) overhead. Namely, it stores the number of characters allocated in the memory block.

Comment: @NicolBolas: And how does `free` know how much to free? `malloc` will store the number of bytes allocated too.

Comment: @MSalters or some means of finding the following block in memory.  Something like `new MyClass[]` must generally store the exact count as well, in order to call the correct number of destructors, since this information cannot be derived otherwise.  `new char[]` may also do this (for reasons of orthogonality---it won't need the count); the ones I know don't.

Comment: @Als One important difference between `malloc()` and `::operator new()`.  You can legally replace `::operator new()`, and `malloc()` is guaranteed not to use `::operator new()` in its implementation, so you can use `malloc()` in an override of `operator new()`.  (Formally, `malloc` and `free` are the only functions which have this guarantee.  In my implementations of `::operator new()`, It tend to assume that functions like `memset` and `memcpy` don't invoke `::operator new()` either.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, if you need exact N dtors called, then you'd better store N. But I was confirming was hvd said: `new char[N]` is a perfectly sane way to allocate raw memory and, as you confirmed, on many implementations there is no difference in overhead.

Comment: @MSalters Yes.  The standard actually guarantees that `new char[N]` be correctly aligned for all possible types (so the alignment requirements for the return value of `new char[N]` are greater than those for `new int[N]`).  From a readability point of view, however, I'd prefer to see `::operator new(N)` used when the goal is to acquire raw memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Does the guarantee that `malloc()` will never call `::operator new()` arise from the fact that `malloc()` was incorporated in to C++ only for backard compatibility with C, & Is this an implicit guarantee or has the Standards committee specifically & conciously marked `malloc()` for this purpose by stating this explicitly? My question is more about the rationale rather than the exact standard quotes.

Comment: @Als No.  There is (or was at one time) an explicit guarantee that `malloc` will not call `::operator new`.  There was, back in the early days, a certain euphoria about C++, and a belief in certain communities that it would replace C everywhere, and that implementations of C would only exist for reasons of backwards compatibility, and that there would be implementations in which the C library would be written in C++.  So, for example, `printf` would e implemented using `<<` on an `ostream`.  (As far as I know, it's never happened.)

Answer (score 3):

First, when you speak of `new` and `delete`, I assume you mean the
expressions, and not the `operator new` and `operator delete` functions.
The `new` and `delete` expressions are not related to `malloc` and
`free`, and only manage memory incidentally; their main role is to
manage object lifetime: a `new` expression will call the `operator new`
function to obtain memory, and then call the constructor; a `delete`
expression will call the destructor before calling `operator delete` to
free the memory.  For the most part, objects should be *created*, and
not simply *allocated*, which means using the expressions exclusively.

There are some rare cases where one wants to separate allocation and 
initialization (creation); implementing things like `std::vector` is a
classical example, where you'll allocate for many objects in one go, but
only construct one at a time.  In such cases, you'll use the `operator
new` function for allocation, and placement new for initialization; at
the other end, you'll explicitly call the constructor (something like
`p->~T()`) for destruction, and use the `operator delete` function to
free the memory.

Off hand, I can only think of two cases where you'd use `malloc` and
`free` in C++.  The first is to implement your own replacements of the
`::operator new` and `::operator delete` functions.  (I often replace
the global `::operator new` and `::operator delete` with debugging
versions, which trace allocations, put guard zones around the allocated
memory, etc.)  The other is when interacting with a legacy library
written in C: if the library says to pass a pointer to memory allocated
by `malloc` (because it will free it itself using `free`), or more
commonly, returns a pointer to memory allocated by `malloc`, which
you're expected to free, then you must use `malloc` and `free`.  (The
better libraries will provide their own allocation and deallocation
functions, which do more or less what the `new` and `delete` operators
do, but there will always be things like `strdup()`.)

Comment: For those interested in the first use stated in the answer, [How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators) is an good read.

Comment: @Als For 100% conformance, you can use the language, `malloc` and `free`, and nothing else.  Realistically, there are a lot of functions which will simply never allocate memory (like `memset`); I'd consider them safe as well.  Practically, you're probably safe with the entire C library, but my debugging implementations do check for recursion, and do not use more than a `malloc`, `memset` and `memcpy` if `::operator new` is being called recursively (so if `fprintf` does use `::operator new`, I won't end up with infinite recursion).