# Segmentation fault when wxThread::OnExit() is called

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, wxwidgets, gmp

**Update 2:** See the section after my code.

I'm using a thread for calculating PI using the GMP library, but somehow I'm now getting a segmentation fault when `wxThread::OnExit()` is internally in wxWidgets called.

Here is the line in wxWidgets source code: [src/msw/thread.cpp#553](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/66180c31f65d96c00c6f361674688a95166010a9/src/msw/thread.cpp#L553)

Here is the shortened code from my thread entry function:

```cpp
while (i <= m_numIterations && !TestDestroy()) {
    mpf_div(result, perimeter, edgeCount);

    mpf_pow_ui(result, result, 2);
    mpf_ui_sub(result, 1, result);
    mpf_sqrt(result, result);
    mpf_div_ui(result, result, 2);

    mpf_sub(result, half, result);
    mpf_sqrt(result, result);
    mpf_mul_ui(result, result, 2);
    mpf_mul(result, result, edgeCount);

    mpf_set(perimeter, result);

    i++;
    mpf_mul_ui(edgeCount, edgeCount, 2);
}

// Free GMP variables we don't need anymore
mpf_clear(half);
mpf_clear(result);
mpf_clear(edgeCount);

// OUTPUT_DIGITS has a constant value, e.g. 12
char outputStr[OUTPUT_DIGITS];

mp_exp_t *expptr;

// If commented out, the error does not appear!
mpf_get_str(outputStr, expptr, 10, OUTPUT_DIGITS, perimeter);
```

**Update 2:** If I comment out the last line with `mpf_get_str()`, the error does not occur.

I also found a very old bug requests from 2003: http://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2003-November/000888.html

Call stack from GCC Debugger:

```
#0 63AE80E9 wxThreadInternal::DoThreadOnExit(thread=0x2cfa978) (../../src/msw/thread.cpp:553)
#1 63B27ACF wxScopeGuardImpl1<void (*)(wxThread*) (../../include/wx/scopeguard.h:168)
#2 63B3F95B wxPrivate::OnScopeExit<wxScopeGuardImpl1<void (*)(wxThread*) (../../include/wx/scopeguard.h:67)
#3 63B27B36 wxScopeGuardImpl1<void (*)(wxThread*) (../../include/wx/scopeguard.h:166)
#4 63AE82FB wxThreadInternal::DoThreadStart(thread=0x2cfa978) (../../src/msw/thread.cpp:561)
#5 63AE83F2 wxThreadInternal::WinThreadStart(param=0x2cfa978) (../../src/msw/thread.cpp:602)
#6 75C4906A ui64tow() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#7 75C49147 msvcrt!iswalnum() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#8 76448543 UnregisterBadMemoryNotification() (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll:??)
#9 00000000 0x02cfb178 in ??() (??:??)
#10 00000000    0x77e8ac69 in ??() (??:??)
#11 00000000    0x77e8ac3c in ??() (??:??)
#12 00000000    0x00000000 in ??() (??:??)
```

Comment: If it's a constant size, why are you dynamically allocating it?

Comment: You're right. I've just tried it but it now throws a segmentation fault when `wxThread::OnExit()` is called!

Comment: It should throw an exception, not return `NULL`. Also, your assert that follows is wrong.

Comment: **Note** that I've changed the question and the code. `outputStr` is now allocated on the stack.

Comment: Which version of GMP are you using? [V4.1])(http://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/) was causing a similar error on Windows 7 x64 in this code: `char *data = mpz_get_str(NULL, base, gmpInt); std::string output(data); free(data);`. In my case, the segmentation fault was produced by the call to `free` and I assumed that `mpz_get_str` probably allocates memory in some funky way, without providing any (obvious) means of deallocating it. I managed to get around it by using MPIR on Windows and the latest version of GMP on Linux.

Comment: @MihaiTodor Thanks for your comment and thanks that you have remembered me to post the solution. The problem was that `expptr` was not initialized (i.e. you have to `new` it, GMP doesn't do it for you!)

Comment: @ComFreek I find it rather odd that you're using `new` on it, since you're calling the C version of the GMP API. I would expect to use `malloc` and `free` in this case, but anyway, I'm glad you managed to make it work.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I've already seen the C++ wrapper. But I don't see any reason to use it in my small PI program if it's only a wrapper.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm saying: If you're using C stuff, then don't mix it with C++ stuff like `new` and `delete`, because, by doing this, you're definitely asking for trouble ;)

Comment: @MihaiTodor Have you any links about this topic? I would be interested for my future projects.

Comment: It has been discussed plenty of times on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972212/why-use-malloc-free-when-we-have-new-delete

Comment: @MihaiTodor Thanks. I'll consider them in my future projects. But AFAIK GMP does not `new` or `delete` any passed parameters. So it's safe (meaning that it won't break something directly) to use here.

Comment: @ComFreek Well, it's your code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent pointer (here `expptr`) has to be already initialized to an object.

This one-liner solves the problem:

```
expptr = new mp_exp_t();

// call mpf_get_str()
```

I also want to note that VZ. was right that GDB (GNU Debugger) *can* show the wrong line of source code in which the error should appear.

So do not *only* rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

new doesn't "fail", per se, you've got heap corruption somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed my question since you answered. But I'm still getting a segmentation fault, see my text.

Comment: you still have corruption somewhere.. moving an item from the heap to the stack doesn't change that.  run it in a debugger, it might fault near or on where the corruption actually happens.

Comment: you might also try valgrind if you're on linux... it'll run a lot slower, effectively in an emulator, but it can pick up on invalid pointer access, stack overrun, etc.

Comment: I've put the call stack into my question. I'm on Windows.

Comment: `new` can certainly fail, but that's probably not the problem here.  `new` will throw an exception if it cannot allocate the requested amount of memory, and `new (nothrow)` will return a null pointer.

Comment: @EdS. Thanks for the info. I didn't know that before.

Comment: @Ed S: technically you are 100% correct, but for practical purposes, new doesn't fail if you're using it in a normal way...

Comment: @mark: Sure it does, just not often.  By your logic you should never check for `malloc` returning a null pointer either because you are using it in a "normal way".  I'm also not sure how you would use it in an "abnormal way".

Answer (score 0):

If it really crashes on this line (there is also a non negligible probability that gdb just gets lost and doesn't show the subsequent frames), then the `thread` pointer itself must be NULL or invalid which can't happen in normal execution, so I do agree with the other reply: something seems to corrupt your variables. But do check if your `OnExit()` gets entered at all just in case gdb is lying.

And as you're using cross-platform libraries, you should be able to rebuild under Linux and run it under valgrind which should pin point all the obvious problems.