# error C2661: 'CObject::operator new' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments visual studio related

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

This isn't about C++ but my issue is about visual studio 2013. I get this error in all of my .cpp files when i'm trying to compile. I have not made any changes to my code and i have done the following steps to remedy the issue to no avail

1)Delete my code base and check out a clean version

2) Reinstall visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 5

3)Reset my visual studio settings and imported my colleagues settings

4)Code revision history doesn't show any modifications to definition of macro new

Funny thing is all my colleagues are able to compile and I'm able to compile in release mode . This issue exists only in debug mode. I'm hoping someone has encountered this before and has a solution for this.

Comment: Have you got some funky `ifdef _DEBUG` action going on? Or maybe you've got something weird with a macro'd `new`?

Comment: As i said above, there is no changes in the code so no issue of weird ifdefi_debug action. The soulution file has also not been touched to change the macro. The code compiles and runs fine in debug mode in my laptop and my colleagues workstations.

Comment: If you add a new simple, do-nothing class to the same project (either via ClassWizard or manually - I'd try both actually), can you reproduce the same compiler error?

Comment: I added a new class both through the wizard and manually and tried to instantiate the class using new and still getting the same error. I'm wondering if there is a compiler related settings file in Visual Studio which is corrupted and doesn't get overwritten when i do a reinstall?

Comment: @user2832424 See if this answer helps or gives you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914486/6610379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Compiled a different branch to see if it works and it compiled. Then i compiled the branch which was causing the error and it was fixed. Have no clue why the issue was being caused in the first place.