# Basic new/delete operator logging

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I'd like to overload global and non-global new/delete operators for logging.

As I just want to add logging informations, I'd like to keep the standard behavior of this operators.

Is there a way to overload new/delete operator to add logging but without having to rewrite the standard behavior (which might be error prone) ?

Actually, I not only need standard behavior. I need the same behavior as Visual 2010 implementations, which might be not standard.

The kind of error I am looking for with this kind of logging is new[]/delete mismatch.

I could use classic tools but they slowdown the execution and I'd like to share the binary with other people to gather more informations.

Comment: I believe that if you just call malloc you will preserve the standard behaviour. Whether you'll preserve the precise behaviour of the operator new you are replacing is another matter.

Comment: Any attempts made so far? What were the problems you encountered in your attempts?

Comment: The default behaviour isn't terribly complex, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you do it properly, there'll be a loop and calls to `get_new_handler`, I suppose. Make sure not to use standard containers inside the allocation functions, unless you give them a different allocator that doesn't itself use `operator new`.

Comment: @john Thank you, I added information to my question, I do not only need standard behavior, I need the same behavior as Visual 2010 implementation.

Comment: @ViteFalcon No attempts. The problem is that I can't simply "try" and hope for the best. The software I work on is defense-sensitive and I'd like to propose adding information to new and delete to fight memory leaks. If I can be sure that the implementation I propose can not add bugs, that would help me.

Comment: I have never tried, but overloading the operator should not prevent you from calling the default implementation when you are done with your own stuff, does it ?

Comment: @Ubiquité I'm pretty sure the source code for the operator new implementation is available in Visual Studio. So you could just find that. However if you are doing this to find memory leaks, then a) not all memory leaks will result from incorrect use of new, b) wouldn't you be better using a dedicated leak detection tool rather than trying to write your own?

Comment: @Ubiquité : have you never heard of prototyping ? You can't make something on the first try ever, you always to play around to understand the scope of your problem !

Comment: From [this excellent FAQ question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7194127/743214) you see that it isn't really that involved to write your own standard conformant `operator new/delete`, just some 5-10 lines of boilerplate, plus your logging functionality and a call to `std::malloc/free`.

Comment: @J.N. There is tones of different use case to try. So it would be more efficient to share the "logging-producing" binary.

Comment: @john Thank you, I found this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t48aek43%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/248aa748%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use `malloc`/`free` for the basic allocation.  Handling full
standards compliance for `new` is a bit tricky; you need something like:

```
void*
operator new( size_t n )
{
    void* results = malloc( n );
    while ( results == NULL ) {
        if ( std::get_new_handler() == NULL ) {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }
        (*std::get_new_handler())();
        results = malloc( n );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Often, however, you don't need such full compliance.  If you say that
you don't support setting the `new_handler`, for example, you can
simplify greatly.  In the overloaded version I use for testing, in fact,
if `malloc` really fails, I abort (but this version has options to
trigger a failure of `new`, on demand, since I want to test that my code
reacts correctly to it as well).

If you're logging, be very careful to avoid endless recursion.  The only
functions guaranteed not to use `operator new` in the standard library
are `malloc` and `free`.  Of course, a lot have no reason to allocate
dynamically, and I don't worry about functions like `memcpy` or
`strlen`.  In practice, you are probably safe with any of the functions
in the C library (although in theory, `printf` could be implemented in
terms of `iostream`).  But any use of iostream, locale or the standard
containers is out, unless you protect against recursion:

```
void*
operator new( size_t n )
{
    static int recursionCount = 0;
    ++ recursionCount;
    void* results = malloc() ;
    //  Any additional logic you need...
    if ( recursionCount == 1 ) {
        logAllocation( results, n );
    }
    -- recursionCount;
    return results;
}
```

Formally, you should do the same for `operator delete`, although in
practice, if you're logging to a file, I wouldn't expect any `delete`
except in `close()` or the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `new` keyword to call a different signature and pass `__FILE__` and such.

In the general case this works out OK.  When you start using objects that override `operator new` though you kinda screw yourself.

If I knew it by memory I'd share, but you can probably find with google.  I think there's an implementation on codeproject somewhere.