# SIMD and dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, sse, simd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSE, intrinsics, and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502071/sse-intrinsics-and-alignment)

I'm new to SIMD programming, so please excuse me if I'm asking an obvious question.

I was experimenting a bit and got to a point where I want to store a SIMD value in a dynamically allocated structure.

Here's the code:

```
struct SimdTest
{
    __m128      m_simdVal;

    void setZero()
    {
        __m128 tmp = _mm_setzero_ps(); 
        m_simdVal = tmp; // <<--- CRASH ---
    }
};

TEST( Plane, dynamicallyAllocatedPlane )
{
    SimdTest* test = new SimdTest();

    test->setZero();

    delete test;
}
```

When the method marked with CRASH comment is executed, the code crashes with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x775315de in test-core.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

Could someone please explain why does the assignment operation break, and how should SIMD-containing objects be allocated dynamically so that they work fine?

I need to add that if I statically instantiate a SimdTest object and call the setZero method, everything works fine.

Thanks,
Paksas

Comment: Looks like you're the newest victim of misalignment. `new` doesn't sufficiently align to 16 bytes.

Comment: There has to be a good duplicate of this somewhere out there.

Comment: Yes - that was definately it. When I added a custom allocator to the class that aligned the allocated memory addresses to a 16byte boundary, everything started working fine.

Comment: Try: __declspec(align(16)) SimdTest * test = ...

Comment: @stark No, that would rather align the pointer variable itself, which is not neccessary, it's the memory allocated and whose address is assigned to the pointer which needs alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It dies because the structure is mis-aligned.  The CRT allocator only promises alignment to 8, 16 is required here.  You'll need to use _aligned_malloc() on MSVC to get properly aligned heap allocated memory.

Two ways to go about it.  Since this is a POD struct, you could just cast:

```
#include <malloc.h>
...
    SimdTest* test = (SimdTest*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof SimdTest, 16);
    test->setZero();
    _aligned_free(test);
```

Or you could override the new/delete operators for the struct:

```
struct SimdTest
{
    void* operator new(size_t size) { return _aligned_malloc(size, 16); }
    void operator delete(void* mem) { return _aligned_free(mem); }
    // etc..
};
```

Comment: As a side note, there is usually a bit more to the implementation of those overloads and there should also be overloads for the other `new/delete` versions (and likewise specializations for `std::allocator`). I know you know this, just to remark it for any other readers, so +1 anyway.

Answer (score -1):

MSDN states that the _m128 are automaticly aligned by 16 bytes, not __m128, but _m128. But anyway i guess the others right, as i recall there are two kind of move instructions, one for aligned movAps and one for unaligned - movUps. First requires 16b aligment and other don't. Don't know if compiler are capable of using both, but i'd tryed this _m128 type.

Actually there are special type for that: _M128A.

Comment: I don't think that there exist types `_m128` or `_M128A`. And `__m128` *is* automatically aligned to 16 bytes, but that doesn't always work (e.g. when doing dynamic allocation).

Comment: The `__m128` types (yes, it's `__m128` not `_m128`, which I've never heard about) are properly aligned if allocated on the stack (e.g. as automatic variables). But this doesn't help when allocating them dynamically (e.g. using `new`).