# Dynamic array alignment in gcc/g++

Tags: android, c++11, sse

I plan using SSE instructions applied to elements of int16_t array. Is there a way to force 16 byte alignment with new operator or uique_ptr semantics?

```
int16_t *array=new int16_t[N];
```

Is the only possibility is to use `posix_memalign`? I assume that using

```
int16_t *array __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

will align the pointer itself only.

Comment: See: [SSE, intrinsics, and alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502071/sse-intrinsics-and-alignment).

Comment: @PeterCordes: I don't think that works for `new`, which typically calls `malloc` and returns memory with whatever the platform's alignment requirement is (often 16 bytes, but can be just 8). See the linked question in my comment above.

Comment: @PaulR: thanks, it looks like you're right.  I was misremembering, probably confusing it with the static / local alignment case where the union with `__m128i` trick does work.  And Wojciech: yes `posix_memalign` is a good choice, because it returns a pointer that is guaranteed to be freeable with `free()`.  Pointers from `_mm_malloc` are not guaranteed to work with `free()`.  You'd better check on `operator delete`, too, if you want to have that work for sure.