# Adding slightly shifted vectors

Tags: c++, performance, simd, cpu-registers, avx2

I am working on code which I want to vectorize with C++. I am using AVX2 with doubles so vector length=4,

I am having difficulties to determine what is the optimal thing to do in my case where I have a memory aligned vector `b` that I want to add a another vector `a`, no problem.
Then I want to add a vector `c` to `a` where the starting point of `c` is 8 bytes to left in memory compared to the starting point of `b`.

I have been thinking about shifting `b` one to right, masking the first value of `b` to zero, adding `b` to `a` and finally loading the one scalar double left to the starting address of `b` and adding that to the to first place in `a`.
Could it do also that I load the vector left of `b`, blend and shuffle to get `c` and add that to `c`. But from what I have read shuffle instructions seem expensive so I have been wondering is there a better way to get/add a vector that is `n` elements shifted of a vector that I have already loaded to register.

Comment: Would help to see some code.

Comment: Often just load again from memory: modern CPUs have at least 2/clock load throughput, and pretty good performance for cache-line splits and even page-splits.  And yeah, it would take multiple shuffle uops otherwise, without AVX-512 `vpalignq` to take a window from the concatenation of two registers.  If you're fully bottlenecked on load ports already and there's front-end bandwidth + SIMD ALU idle cycles, then consider shuffling, though.  Like maybe unroll by 2 and use an unaligned load for one `c` and a shuffle for the other `c`.  Perhaps `vperm2f128` / `vshufpd`; does that work?

Comment: @PeterCordes, Hi thank you for your answer! When you mean load again, do you mean to load `c` as a vector value, even though it is not aligned, or as four separate scalar values?

Comment: From what I read from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147378/choice-between-aligned-vs-unaligned-x86-simd-instructions, unaligned loads don't seem that bad, so maybe simply loading `c` as a vector isn't that bad

Comment: I mean `_mm256_loadu_ps` of course, to get all 32 bytes from a single uop for a load execution unit.  (And if you're using an older GCC, see [Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726) to make sure it doesn't split it into 128-bit halves.  You should use a `-march=` anyway, although `-march=x86-64-v3` I think just leaves `-mtune=generic`).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! I was under the impression that unaligned memory accesses would be significantly worse, but seems that they aren't that bad for vector values

Comment: Yeah, problems like yours aren't rare in real life.  Early CPUs with SIMD didn't have the transistor budgets to support unaligned vector loads efficiently, but for x86 at least, that changed around 2008 (Nehalem / K10 / Bulldozer).  Old guides are still floating around, as is folk wisdom from people that learned about SIMD back in the day when using it at all pretty much required aligning your data (or on other ISAs which maybe were later to get efficient unaligned vector loads than x86, since they aimed at smaller transistor budgets, or because x86 has always been more unaligned-friendly)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.