# MSVC generating unnecessary complicated instructions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, compiler-optimization, stdoptional

While benchmarking code involving `std::optional<double>`, I noticed that the code MSVC generates runs at roughly half the speed compared to the one produced by clang or gcc. After spending some time reducing the code, I noticed that MSVC apparently has issues generating code for `std::optional::operator=`. Using `std::optional::emplace()` does not exhibit the slow down.

The following function

```
void test_assign(std::optional<double> & f){
    f = std::optional{42.0};
}
```

produces

```
sub     rsp, 24
vmovsd  xmm0, QWORD PTR __real@4045000000000000
mov     BYTE PTR $T1[rsp+8], 1
vmovups xmm1, XMMWORD PTR $T1[rsp]
vmovsd  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1
add     rsp, 24
ret     0
```

Notice the unaligned mov operations.
On the contrary, the function

```
void test_emplace(std::optional<double> & f){
    f.emplace(42.0);
}
```

compiles to

```
mov     rax, 4631107791820423168      ; 4045000000000000H
mov     BYTE PTR [rcx+8], 1
mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rax
ret     0
```

This version is much simpler and faster.
These were generated using MSVC 19.32 with `/O2 /std:c++17 /DNDEBUG /arch:AVX`.

clang 14 with `-O3 -std=c++17 -DNDEBUG -mavx` produces

```
movabs  rax, 4631107791820423168
mov     qword ptr [rdi], rax
mov     byte ptr [rdi + 8], 1
ret
```

in both cases.

Replacing `std::optional<double>` with

```
struct MyOptional {
    double d;
    bool hasValue; // Required to reproduce the problem
    
    MyOptional(double v) {
        d = v;
    }

    void emplace(double v){
        d = v;
    }
};
```

exhibits the same issue. Apparently MSVC has some troubles with the additional `bool` member.

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bj5d6E9Yr) for a live example.

Why is MSVC producing these unaligned moves? I.e. the question is not why they are unaligned rather than aligned (which wouldn't improve things according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466585/3740047) post). But why does MSVC produce a considerably more expensive set of instructions in the assignment case?
Is this simply a bug (or missed optimization opportunity) by MSVC? Or am I missing something?

Comment: reading the gobolt code this is due to the use of that struct.still odd tho

Comment: Looks to me like it is trying to write combine the bool and double into a vector op. One of those *compiler is trying to clever* mis-optimizations.

Comment: @user17732522 oops sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697118/visual-studio-2017-mm-load-ps-often-compiled-to-movups/45466585#45466585

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, sorry, I just fixed it. Besides this, I don't think that the [answer from the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466585/3740047) answers the problem here. The other answer basically says "unaligned load/stores do not cost anything compared to aligned load/stores". But in the case here the compiler generates a bunch of additional instructions (regardless if they are unaligned or whatever) that are unnecessary in the first place (as shown by clang). And the additional instruction do cost performance.

Comment: If it had put the entire 16-byte `std::optional<double>` in static memory, and copied it with `vmovups xmm1, [static_constant] / vmovups [rcx], xmm1` it might not have been so bad. But instead it puts only the `double` constant in static memory, constructs the `std::optional<double>` on the stack, and *then* copies it to its destination.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Actually it doesn't ever copy the `double` to the stack, it stores a `1` with a byte store, then does a 16-byte load, then replaces the low 8 bytes of the XMM register with a `movsd` register blend.  So storing to the stack and reloading was just a way to get a `1`  into byte 8 of an XMM register, with the rest being don't-care garbage.  Taking 2 instructions and creating a store-forwarding stall, horrible vs. `vpcmpeqd xmm1,xmm1,xmm1` / `vpabsd xmm1, xmm1`.  And then obviously if you want to merge a new low half from memory, `movlps` not `movsd`-load + `movsd xmm,xmm`.

Comment: Anyway, yeah, MSVC is fairly widely considered / known [not to be as good an optimizing compiler as clang or GCC](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=1015).  The problem isn't that the `vmovups` instructions aren't `vmovaps`; the address likely is 16-byte aligned, since it knows the incoming stack alignment.  The problem is the store-forwarding stall from narrow store, wide reload!  (GCC isn't immune from shooting itself in the foot, too, though: [Bubble sort slower with -O3 than -O2 with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69503317))