# new operator in c++

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm reading the chapter 13 of "Thinking in c++".
The following comes from the book.

> MyType *fp = new MyType(1, 2);
>
> at runtime, the equivalent of
> malloc(sizeof(MyType)) is called, **and the constructor for MyType is
> called with the resulting address as the this pointer**, using (1, 2) as
> the argument list. By the time the pointer is  assigned to fp.

I'm confused by the bold sentence. What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very loose explanation, but it's basically saying that the result is a memory location, just like `malloc` would return, and at that memory location an object is constructed (`this` is a pointer to the current object) using the constructor with that argument list.

Comment: emphasis on _very loose explanation_, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators/) for how much `operator new` has to do beyond `malloc`

Comment: One more question, when and how the this pointer is initialized?

Comment: @FihopZz when the object is created - before the constructor body enters and before member initialization.

Comment: Hi Luchian, I'm kind of confused by your answer. "before the constructor body enters and before member initialization". member initialization must be inside the constructor which means before the constructor body entering indicating before member initialization. Am I right?

Comment: @FihopZz no, some members are initialized before the constructor body (think initialization lists, and all non-POD members)

Answer (score 4):

When the `new` operator allocates memory dynamically, it returns a pointer to that memory (similar to how `malloc()` works in C).

In C++, every non-static method has access to the current object it is called on (else C++ programmers around the world would be in serious trouble). This is an "implicit argument" of the methods, in the constructors as well, and one can access it through the keyword `this`.

What the sentence means is that after creating the object, the operator will call the constructor **on the memory it just allocated.** Because this is the only thing that makes sense. :)

Comment: One more question, when and how the this pointer is initialized?

Comment: @FihopZz Here and by assigning it to the address of the allocated memory region.

Comment: initializing the this pointer happens before calling the constructor or inside the constructor?

Comment: @FihopZz Think a bit about that. If it wasn't already initialized when the constructor is called, then in the constructor, `this` would be garbage, and your program would probably segfault each time you dynamically allocate an object.

Comment: Hi, H2CO3. I'm kind of new to c++. Maybe the question is stupid. I'm still thinking maybe initializing the this pointer is the first task inside constructor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24402/discussion-between-fihopzz-and-h2co3)