# Can c++ new operator automatically use large pages on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

Let's say I've written a C++ program using Visual Studio and it uses the new operator to allocate memory. I'm wondering whether there is a way that makes new automatically use large pages instead of standard 4KB pages (i.e., without explicit calls to VirtualAlloc by my program).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `new` doesn't even use 4KB pages. It uses `HeapAllocate`. It would be absurd for a `new` of 32 bytes to allocate 4MB of nonpageable memory. If that's what you want, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: @RaymondChen- Are you *sure* that's what `new` does?  Isn't it implementation-dependent?

Comment: Does Windows or a C++ runtime library (or something like it) manage the heap for the C++ program? My understanding is that the C++ heap manager gets pages (4K or larger) from the OS, and allocates part of it to the user's C++ program. Isn't it so?

Comment: @templatetypedef - the question was about Visual Studio - it is an implementaiton.

Comment: Visual Studio comes with C runtime source code. You can read for yourself what `new` does.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Did you just ask _the_ Raymond Chen if he is sure about something related to Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators)

Answer (score 3):

You can override all **new** and **delete** operators. For example

```
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void * pointer)
{
    free(pointer);
}
```

As well you should override all variants of this operators:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/

Comment: Yup, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators?lq=1) for more information on how to do this the correct way. Naturally, you would want to call `VirtualAlloc` to use large pages.

Answer (score 1):

> Implementation specific, once again. All libraries are not restricted
>   to doing that since all the standard says AFAIK is that new allocates
>   memory for C++. For Microsoft's implementation, new always calls
>   HeapAlloc.

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/98364-new-invokes-virtualalloc.html

My understanding is that unless you're running in a virtual machine, the OS has full control over the default heap and stack memory allocation.  The above link also brings up a good point in line with Raymond's response to your question: Are you sure you need to use large pages?  You open yourself to a good deal of internal fragmentation by doing so.