# Use specific block of memory for member variables of a class

Tags: c++

I wanted to use only a specific block of memory for the class so that for an object, its member variables are allocated memory from the same block. And if the object goes out of the scope, then the memory block is again available for reuse.

Comment: You'll probably need to overload `operator new` for the class, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- [Overload the `new` operator for your class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators/) or
- Use [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html)