# Using placement new in generic programming

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, generic-programming, placement-new, c++-faq

When using placement new in generic code to construct an object at a specified address, the usage pattern is a bit different from usual code.  For example, consider this implementation of `uninitialized_copy`: ([[uninitialized.copy]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/uninitialized.copy#lib:uninitialized_copy))

```
template <class It, class For>
For uninitialized_copy(It first, It last, For dest)
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<For>::value_type;
    for (; first != last; ++first, (void)++dest)
        ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*dest))) T(*first);
}
```

This post addresses the following points from the perspective of the standard:

- why `::new` is used instead of just `new`;
- why an explicit cast to `void*` is required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(This answer uses N4659, the final C++17 draft.)

## Why `::new` is used instead of just `new`

`::new` ensures that the `operator new` is looked up in the global scope.  In contrast, the plain `new` first looks up in the scope of the class if `T` is a class type (or array thereof), and only then falls back to the global scope.  Per [[expr.new]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#9):

> If the *new-expression* begins with a unary ​`::`​ operator, the
>   allocation function's name is looked up in the global scope.
>   Otherwise, if the allocated type is a class type `T` or array thereof,
>   the allocation function's name is looked up in the scope of `T`. If
>   this lookup fails to find the name, or if the allocated type is not a
>   class type, the allocation function's name is looked up in the global
>   scope.

For example, with

```
struct C {
    void* operator new(std::size_t, void* ptr) noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Hello placement new!\n";
        return ptr;
    }
};
```

The plain `new` will cause this function to be found, thus printing unwanted message, whereas `::new` will still find the global function and work properly.

The global `operator new(std::size_t, void*)` cannot be replaced because of [[new.delete.placement]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/new.delete.placement#1):

> **These functions are reserved; a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the C++ standard library
>   ([constraints]).** The provisions of [basic.stc.dynamic] do not apply
>   to these reserved placement forms of `operator new` and `operator
>   delete`.

(See [How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7194127) for more about overloading `operator new`.)

## Why an explicit cast to `void*` is required

Although the global `operator new(std::size_t, void*)` may not be replaced, new versions of `::operator new` can be defined.  For example, suppose that the following declaration is placed in the global scope:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t, int* ptr) noexcept
{
    std::cout << "Hello placement new!\n";
    return ptr;
}
```

Then `::new(ptr) T` will use this version instead of the global version, where `ptr` is a `int*` value.  The pointer is explicitly cast to `void*` to ensure that the `void*` version of `operator new` (which we intend to call) wins in overload resolution.

---

From comment:

> But why do we want to call exactly global `new` for `void*` if some
>   type has special overload of new for itself? Seems like normal
>   overloaded operator is more suitable - why it's not?

Normally, `new` is used for allocation purposes.  Allocation is something the user should have control over.  The user can roll out more suitable versions for a normal `new`.

In this case, however, we don't want to allocate anything — all we want to do is create an object!  The placement new is more of a "hack" — its presence is largely due to the lack of syntax available for constructing an object at a specified address.  We don't want the user to be able to customize anything.  The language itself, however, doesn't care about this hack, though — we have to treat it specially.  Of course, if we have something like `construct_at` (which is coming in C++20), we will use it!

Also note that `std::uninitialized_copy` is intended for the simplest case where you just want to copy construct a sequence of objects in raw allocated space.  The standard containers allow you to customize not only how the elements are *allocated*, but also how they are *constructed*, by means of an allocator.  Therefore, they do not generally use `std::uninitialized_copy` for their elements — they call `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct`.  This feature is used by `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`.

Comment: @Qwertiy For placement `new`, only the global version is suitable - we don't want to allocate anything.  The sole purpose of the placement `new` is to construct an object at the specified address.  Calling a user-defined will screw up.

Comment: Then why used made an overload for it? So at the same time we allow user to make an overload, but want to bypass it when creating an object?

Comment: @Qwertiy Yeah.  We only want to create an object; we don't intend to call any user-defined function except the constructor.

Comment: @Qwertiy I've updated the answer to address your questions.

Comment: Yep, see it. Nice :)