# Class specific new/delete

Tags: c++

Is it possible to overload class specific new/delete that is called when arrays of objects are created.

```
class Foo;

Foo* f = new Foo[10]; // calls overloaded new
delete[] f; // calls overloaded delete
```

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-should-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-should-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is a tutorial about overloading `new` and `delete` [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html), and there is a nice example of overloading `new` and `delete` *for array*, [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0139.shtml).

```
class Myclass
{
  public:
        void* operator new(size_t); 
        void operator delete(void*);

        void* operator new[](size_t); 
        void operator delete[](void*);
};
```