# Can i get the type of object for which new operator is used inside the overloaded new operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, overloading, new-operator

Well i have this function overload:

```
static bool returnNull;    
void* operator new(const std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    void* address{ nullptr };
    if (!returnNull)
    {
        address = operator new(size);
    }
    return address;
}
```

And i want to make something like:

```
void* operator new(const std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    if (typeObject == AnimalClass)
        return nullptr;
    void* address{ nullptr };
    if (!returnNull)
    {
        address = operator new(size);
    }
    return address;
}
```

So, i need this functionality for unit testing a builder that have many new calls, so i want to fail a specific allocation based on Class that should be alocated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is the problem you're facing with your code?

Comment: you can define [class-specific new and delete operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543114/class-specific-new-delete) if that helps

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: Why do you want *either* of these `new`s? Note that you are inviting `std::terminate` by not catching any `std::bad_alloc` thrown by `::new(size_t)`

Comment: This could be an interesting question. Unfortunately, I think that the language has no provision for that, And because of that it is turning into an x-y problem. IMHO, you should get one step back and wonder why you wanted to reject allocation of `AnimalClass` in that test and whether a different design is possible. This way is definitely a dead end.

Comment: Well, the main reason is that i want to test if application behaviour is ok in case of not enough memory(or any other failure of new operator)

Comment: And related to std::badaloc, in my app i use std::nothrow because i dont want exceptions

Answer (score 0):

What your code does can be achieved by `new` operator overloading for class `AnimalClass`:

```
class AnimalClass
{
public:

   #ifdef UNIT_TEST
   void* operator new(size_t)
   {
      return nullptr;
   }
   #endif
};
```

You can use `#ifdef` preprocessor directive to keep the code outside of tests. Define `UNIT_TEST` before header including.

Comment: Yes, but i want to test the class. I dont want to change its behavior outside test

Comment: @ArronStowne, сonsider the preprocessor options, it helped me in similar cases.